# Where is the tomb of Genghis Khan located?

Tags: mongol-empire

Genghis Khan the great Mongol Ruler conquered most of Eurasia. His empire extended from China to Poland. But there is a mystery where he was buried after his death. It still remains a mystery.

Comment: an entire book could be written about this topic... 

Comment: @Kobunite- truly said.i am also searching a lot on the same topic since long time.hoping to get some new clue here.

Comment: @ Mark C. Wallace- as you wish bro.just finding if i get a new link somewhere.i have  read all available material on the topic.Still tickles my mind so i put it forward here.

Comment: Well, if the answer is "nobody knows", IMHO that's still an answer. :-)

Comment: Still closed though, as the answer is readily available on wikipedia.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is [nobody knows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_of_Genghis_Khan). There were no first-hand written accounts of the burial, and even legend is inconsistent in the matter.

It is quite likely there **isn't any tomb to be found**. Altaic peoples such as the Mongols [often practiced open-air "burials"](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/corff/im/Texte/burial.html)

> When the right time had come, the corpse was usually placed on a cart
>   (tärgä) pulled by horse or cow. Then the bereaved men of the family
>   followed the cart to the clan's or family's burial place, which was an
>   uninhabited area separate from the areas used by the nomads. These
>   places were sacred and only visited for funeral-related events.
>
> In other areas, especially in South Mongolia, the corpse was placed on
>   a horse's back and upon reaching the funeral site, the horse was urged
>   to gallop until the corpse was thrown off.
>
> Some stones were put next to the head in order to recognize the burial
>   site later. Then a fire was made to sacrifice the select pieces of
>   (lamb) meat and white dishes (cagaan idää).
>
> Depositing the corpse in the steppe was meant to sacrifice it to
>   predatory animals. According to Mongolians this is the last virtous
>   act a person can carry out. This idea is much older than Lamaism and
>   exhibits a really strong shamanistic element of spiritual thought.

Comment: I've also read claims that all the servants who assisted with the *final rites* were killed to keep the location secret.

Comment: but i think there would be a tomb somewhere. The legend says he was buried with the crowns of all the kings and princes he defeated.A lot of jewellery was also buried along with him.

Comment: @hRb - The "legend" appears to have orignated in China, which does use tombs. But Mongolia at the time did not. So that legend is most likely a Chinese invention.